# Rails Associations: access join table by console (HABTM)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-console

I got what I wanted - has and belongs to many associations, using the simple directives from the Rails Guides. In the console it all works just fine, but I am kind of stuck with the following.

Let's say I have two models **Article** and **Category**, which both have the directive has_and_belongs_to_many in their models and corresponding to the articles_categories table in the database. In rails console I can see the association working with statements such as these:

```
%>   @x = Article.find(1)
%>   @x.categories
```

This way I have a collection of categories stored inside @x. Wonderful. But I cannot really find a way how I could 'add' through console a new category. Right now, I am using SQL to insert the values into the jointable. I am hoping there is a much smarter, Railsy way to do something like this

```
%> @x.article.categories.category_id = 1  # id of category
%> @x.article.categories.article_id = 1  # id of article
%> @x.save # and written to the database
```

I am specifically looking for the way to do this in the rails console - so I actually get the feeling of what is happening instead of code snippets that work and I don't get. I am using Rails **4.1.6**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can simply add to the `categories` collection and Rails will manage the database relationships.

```
> category = Category.find(1)
> article = Article.find(1)
> article.categories << category
> article.save
```

This will add an articles_categories record with an article_id of 1 and a category_id of 1. And, even better, the objects will know about each other:

```
> article.categories.include?(category) # => true
> category.articles.include?(article) # => true
```

Comment: Can it be this easy? If this works, I declare you God!

Comment: I seriously love you for this.

Answer (score 1):

Why dont you try:

```
@article.categories.build (params)
```

where params will contain attributes for the new category

Comment: Wouldn't you need to set up an accepts_nested_attributes_for to do this (and change the HABTM to has_many through)?